# CosmosBoot with Mono on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

Is it possible to install Cosmos User Kit(A C# Operating System) with mono on mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Cosmos User Kit doesn't support Mono, yet.

Comment: however I believe they will consider Mono and vice versa.